# Rust: print out string character by character

Tags: python, rust

The task it to print the text of the string to the terminal, character by character, using Rust.

Here is my code:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
    let string = "You are the Semicolon to my Statements.";

    for c in string.chars() {
        print!("{}", c);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }

    println!();
}
```

When running my code, the string only prints to the terminal after the loop is completed.

How can I print the string character by character?

P.S. Here is a working example in Python 3:

```py
import time

string = "You are the Semicolon to my Statements."

for i in string:
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)

print()
```

Comment: `flush=True` - that's the key difference between the two snippets. You need to find how to do this bit in rust (flush stdout)

Comment: Try using `stdout().flush();`

Answer (score 4):

You need to find how to `flush` in rust, your code should look like this

```
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::Write;

#[allow(unused_must_use)]
fn main() {

   let string = "You are the Semicolon to my Statements.";

   for c in string.chars() {
      print!("{}", c);
      stdout().flush();
      sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
   };

   println!();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, great one. Especially the `#[allow(unused_must_use)]` line, which enables compiler to ignore warning. It's also nice you've included required libraries: `stdout` and `Write`.

Comment: @Alexound You should not use `unused_must_use` in this case. Either handle the `Result` or call `stdout().flush().unwrap()`. `must_use` exists for a good reason and there are better ways to handle it than to disable it for your whole function.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with more functional and/or idiomatic `Rust`:

```
fn main() {
    let test = "Test";

    test.chars()
        .for_each(|c| print!("{}", c));
}
```

I did not experiment with `flush()` but in case you really need it, you could probably add it and test with it:

```
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::Write; 

fn main() {
    let test = "Test";

    test.chars()
        .for_each(|c|  {
            print!("{}", c);
            stdout().flush(); // this is a Result and should be handled properly
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `stdout().flush();` in your loop. This is the Rust synonym of Python's `flush=True`. Try the following code.

```
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::Write;    
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {

   let string = "You are the Semicolon to my Statements.";

   for c in string.chars() {
      print!("{}", c);
      stdout().flush();
      sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
   };

   println!();

}
```

Comment: This code won't work without including required libraries.